# Sparx Enterprise Architect EA: Hierarchical structure of models (BPMN)

Tags: hierarchy, enterprise-architect, bpmn

Is there a best practice in Sparx to model the following scenario?

I have several business processes modelled with BPMN. Most of the pools and lanes are identical.

Question: Is it better to have each process including his copy of the pools and lanes and activities, as shown in the image?
Or would it be better to have an external collection - each pool and lane is in one central location, the tasks are collected there - and the diagram simply show the different processes while reusing some of the activities?

[image: current structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not only the best practice, it is also **mandatory**.

Pools are owned by the Business Process, and Lanes are owned by the pools.

*Reuse* is achieved by assigning the same **PartnerRole** or **PartnerEntity** to the pools

[image]

or, in case of lanes assigning the same **PartitionElementRef**

[image]

**Bonus:** If you do it like this you can leave the names of the Pools and Elements empty. They will automatically show the name of the linked PartnerRole/PartnerEntity/PartitionElemenetRef in the diagrams. So no more headaches in case such a name changes.

Comment: Geert Bellekens, thanks for the answer. I understand it's a best practice and I'd like to know where you find such best practices? Since it's not explicit that we have to do this, that's why I am asking.